# How to Synchronize multiple real time audio streams before mixing them?

Tags: sound, real-time, voice, audio-processing

I have been working on a VoIP solution in which I have to mix multiple audio streams coming from various sources. I have been facing muffled sound after the mixing of streams. I have implemented ASW and AAW techniques from the following paper [Audio mixer for multi-party conferencing in VoIP](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/224127731_Audio_mixer_for_multi-party_conferencing_in_VoIP)

Is there any way to synchronize various streams before addition? I have been searching for a solution for a long time.

Comment: You could choose a master audio source and then perform cross correlations  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation) between the master and each other source. Then you could align the secondary sources to the master source.

Comment: Hi @Izzo, I know about temporal synchronization using cross-correlation. I am more into Group or inter-destination synchronization techniques.